# get the name of child list in a list in R with lapply function

Tags: r, list, lapply

How can I get the name of child list in a list in R? My list is like:

```
 $sd1
     freq value order
 11  1.15    17     0
 12  2.12    13     0
 13  2.81    21     0
 14  4.13    15     0
 15  4.84    18     0
 16  7.54    59     0
 17  9.36    17     0

 $sd2
     freq value order
 31  0.63     4     0
 32  1.54     3     0
 33  3.22     3     0
 34  3.98     4     0
 35  4.66    38     0
 36  7.14     3     0
 37  9.39    29     0

 $sd3
     freq value order
 41  0.97     4     0
 42  2.03     7     0
 43  2.65     4     0
 44  3.34   680     0
 45  4.15     4     0
 46  6.67    10     0
 47  7.51     6     0
 48  8.35     4     0
 49 10.57     4     0
 50 15.97     6     0
```

I'd like to get `sd1`,`sd2`... with `lapply` function and make some changes on each child list of `sd1`, `sd2`, etc.

Comment: Can you be more clear about the changes? You can get the names with `names(my_list)`

Comment: why not simply using `lapply(list, function(x) x)`